# Spark: master local[*] is a lot slower than master local

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

I have an `EC2` set up with `r3.8xlarge (32 cores, 244G RAM)`.

In my `Spark` application, I am reading two csv files from `S3` using `Spark-CSV` from DataBrick, each csv has about 5 millions rows. I am `unionAll` the two DataFrames and running a `dropDuplicates` on the combined DataFrame.

But when I have,

```
 val conf = new SparkConf()
            .setMaster("local[32]")
            .setAppName("Raw Ingestion On Apache Spark")
            .set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "32")
```

Spark is slower than `.setMaster("local")`

Wouldn't it be faster with 32 cores?

Answer (score 0):

Well spark is not a Windows operating system, that it would work at maximum possible capacity from the start, you need to tune it for your usage.

Right now you just bluntly said to spark start and process my stuff on one node with 32 cores. That is not what Spark is good for. It is a distributed system suppose to be run on multi-node cluster, that is where it works best.

Reason is simple, even if you are using 32 core, what about IO issue?
Because now you are using let's if it has run 30 executors, than that is 32 process reading from same disk.

You specified 32 core, what about executor memory?
Did both machine had same ram, where you were testing.

You have specified now specifically that you want 32 partitions, if data is very small that is alot of overhead. Ideally you shouldn't specify partition until you know specifically what you are doing, or you are doing repetitive task, and you know data is going to be exactly similar all time.

If you tune it correctly spark with 32 core will indeed work faster than "local" which is basically running on one core.